# Flutter Web on hover sub menu pop up on the side instead of dropdown

Tags: flutter, web, popup, submenu, onhover

How could we build in flutter sub menu that pops up on the side of the menu item (instead of a dropdown) when the user hovers over a menu item?

I'm posting a picture below of what I would like to have.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnBJY.jpg)

I spent a lot of time trying to search for an option, the best I could do was the ExpansionTile but that's a dropdown sub menu on click, not on hover with a side pop up.

I like the side pop up because it doesn't change the vertical size of the main menu items and I can put a lot on the side items and the entire main menu is always visible.

Update: I found something very close to what I want, which is the Multilevel Drawer package (link https://pub.dev/packages/multilevel_drawer/install). And also this video explaining the package https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8VJ-F-bZORE&t=197s

Comment: [This might be](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/PopupMenuButton-class.html) a good starting point. Not sure it does exactly what you're looking for though.

Comment: If you found solution, even for your own answer, please consider posting it as answer instead editing the question - unless you need further help.